# How to using ckeditor in Odoo

Tags: ckeditor, odoo

I expected integration CKEditor use for fields.Text() into Odoo application instead using default text field of Odoo.

Answer (score 1):

You Can define by just `fields.html` , but make sure you are developing in only V8, because CKEditor is removed from V9.

Comment: Then CKEditor is not needed, as it is removed there.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the ckeditor module installed and the field should be html fields:

```python
body_html = fields.Html('Rich-text Contents')
```

You can also use a widget. Check the documentation of the module:

> In your view definition, use widget="text_html" if you need just html
>   display. In the unlikely case you need specific features of ckeditor,
>   use widget="text_ckeditor4".

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer solved your problems please mark it as a correct answer